# Как связать heroku и nic.ru?

Tags: dns, heroku, domain

Я впервые пытаюсь это сделать, поэтому возникли проблемы. Для начала я, конечно, прочитал про dns, что это и зачем. Купил DNS-хостинг на nic.ru, как и сам домен, конечно. Как было сказано в одном руководстве, я добавил запись вида "www CNAME example.herokudns.com". Подождал сутки, но ничего не изменилось. В другом руководстве было сказано, что нужно сделать запись вида "www CNAME mydomain.ru.", но, опять же, не получилось. Да, я еще плохо разбираюсь в различных видах DNS записях, но помогите, пожалуйста, на данном этапе. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: А что именно "не изменилось" и что именно "не получилось", чего вы пытаетесь достичь  ? что бы что открывалось и по какому имени ? Вообще в большинстве случаев вам известен ip вашего сайта и вы создаете 'A' запись с этим ip. Если heroku вам не говорит ваш ip а требует алиас, то конечно следует писать, что они рекомендуют

Comment: Heroku пишет "incorrect DNS settings". Под "не изменилось" и "не получилось" я имею в виду, что домен не привязался к heroku. То есть зайти на сайт нельзя. В руководстве написано, что нужно использовать следующую запись: Record: "ALIAS or ANAME" Name: "empty or @" Target: "example.herokudns.com.". Но в nic.ru нет записи типа alias или aname. Также в nic.ru сказано, что DNS зона должна содержать не менее двух NS-записей, но об этом в руководстве ничего не сказано

Comment: NS записи вам сам nic.ru дает если вы используете его сервера DNS (а не просто купили домен без серверов). И да, под алиасом имеется ввиду cname. Но главное, под каким именем вы пытаетесь попасть на свой домен, под www.mydomain.ru или просто mydomain.ru ? потому что когда вы пишите запись www, то и получаете только www.mydomain.ru. И как выглядит "не работа", что именно сообщает браузер, идет ли ping на ваше имя. А то может у вас с самим сайтом проблема а не с DNS

Comment: Если писать mydomain.ru, то просто открывается страница, что домен обслуживается компанией ru-center, если www.mydomain.ru, то страница недоступна. Я понял, что alias = cname. Но когда пытаюсь написать в поле alias "@" или оставить его пустым, то появляется предупреждение, что нельзя использовать этот символ. В руководстве сказано, что нужно делать именно так ._.

Comment: Да, если бы вы правили файл конфигурации named, то надо было писать `@`, а вот как ее писать в интерфейсе nic.ru видимо надо выяснять у поддержки nic.ru

Comment: ну и если "страница не доступна", то начинать надо с ping www.mydomain.ru и смотреть, есть ли пинг, если нет, то пытается ли он вообще идти, т.е. определеяет ли ip адрес. Если адрес определяет и правильный - значит со стороны DNS все в порядке и надо уже смотреть web-сервер и прочее

Comment: хоспаде, наконец-то все заработало (по адресу www.mydomain.ru). Сейчас буду пытаться сделать так, что без www работала, но, слава богу, есть куча объяснений, как это сделать. На будущее людям, которые такие же новички, как я, то нужно сделать такую запись "mydomain.tld CNAME example.herokudns.com." (точка в конце). Надо бы разобраться с этим нормально. Большое тебе спасибо)

Comment: для самого домена надо сделать отдельную такую же запись, но вместо www там должно быть: `@` или ничего или домен целиком с точкой на конце (`mydomain.tld.`), по крайней мере в файлах конфигурации эти варианты бы отработали. на nic.ru конечно может быть что то еще